# How would I modify my function to create only one new thread instead of two and still achieve the same sorted result?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mergesort

I am writing a parallel merge sort using `pthreads`. Right now, I am creating two threads and each sorts half the data. Then the results from those two threads are merged. However, I am trying to change my code in the function to instead create only 1 thread without modifying the existing arguments or return type of the function.

So, I am trying to have the function sort half the data itself first and then create only one new thread (instead of two) to sort the other half.

This is the code that I wrote for the function which creates two threads:

```
// sort and return float array x, of length n
// using merge sort
void *pmerge_sort(void *args) {

  // unpack arguments
  Sort_args *sargs = (Sort_args *)args;
  float *x = sargs->x;
  int n = sargs->len;

  // if n < k, the array is sorted directly
  // using another sort algorithm
  int k = 100;
  if (n < k) {
    return(gsort(x, n));
  }

  // create 2 threads; each sorts half the data
  int m = ((float)n)/2.0;

  // pack arguments to recursive call
  Sort_args args1, args2;
  args1.x = x;
  args1.len = m;
  args2.x = &x[m];
  args2.len = n-m;

  int rc;
  pthread_t p1, p2;
  rc = pthread_create(&p1, NULL, pmerge_sort, (void *)&args1);  assert(rc == 0);
  rc = pthread_create(&p2, NULL, pmerge_sort, (void *)&args2);  assert(rc == 0);

  // merge the results from the threads
  float *x1, *x2;
  pthread_join(p1, (void **) &x1);
  pthread_join(p2, (void **) &x2);
  float *y = merge(x1, m, x2, n-m);

  // copy the result back to x and free y
  memcpy((void *)x, (void *)y, n*sizeof(float));
  free(y);

  return (void *)x;
}
```

How would I further modify my code to create only one new thread, but still achieve the same sorted result as in the code that creates two new threads?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort half on the parent and the second on the child then here is one possible solution:

```
  int rc;  
  pthread_t p;
  rc = pthread_create(&p, NULL, pmerge_sort, (void *)&args1);  assert(rc == 0);

  // merge the results from the threads
  float *x1, *x2;

  // let worker thread finish first
  pthread_join(p, (void **) &x1);

  // then sort other half here
  x2 = (float*)(*pmerge_sort)((void *)&args2);

  // then merge
  float *y = merge(x1, m, x2, n-m);
```

There are other ways, we can rearrange how things are done and use polling. However, this is the simplest / smallest change needed to meet your requirements. (change is for first code block)

Comment: Second code block, I do not see were x2 is declared

Comment: Also you may end up creating more threads than two. Example If n > k, where n = 2^x and k = 100. If 2^10 = 1,024 then it will require 5 division before it is less than 100. This would then yield 5 * 2 threads if we use the original design.This is because the function is recursive